# how to change login destination to front page

Tags: 6, users

I have disabled **user login** block. I use Menu link to **user/login** for login. I also used **CAPTCHA** for login page. But now when I log in to site it stays on **user/login** page not redirect to front page and gives me an error **The webpage cannot be found**. Then after refreshing page it shows **Access denied
You are not authorized to access this page.** Any one has idea to set login destination after login.

Comment: It might be worth checking the user table to see if Drupal is logging the user as having just logged in. We recently had a similar problem with a client's site which turned out to be a problem with cookies. If this is the case a good clean out of cache and cookies on the browser should rectify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module. This allows you to react on different events in your system. So it's also possible to redirect the user after he logged in successfully. I think this is the easiest way to achieve this without programming your own module.

Comment: Yes I checked that module. But after setting proper action It gives me again same error.

Comment: Did you try it wit <front>?

Comment: Yes it works I did it with help of steps in  http://drupal.org/node/298506

Answer (score 4):

I think the [Login Destination-module](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) is what you're looking for! Easy to configure and works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Use destination parameter in login links (if you use login form on separated page), you can set it in menu item settings (path change from `user/login` to `user/login?destination=path/to/page`).

This is better than using Rules because rule reacting on user login destroys Passwords reset process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it programmatically by editing your theme's template.php file.

```
function YourThemeName_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
        // on submit execute the YourThemeName_user_login_submit function
        $form['#submit'][] = 'YourThemeName_user_login_submit';
    } 
}

function YourThemeName_user_login_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    // redirect use to the homepage (front) on login
    $form_state['redirect'] = '<front>';
}
```

Just change the *YourThemeName* bit of the two functions to your theme's name. I hope this helps.